# how to get session cookie from server and set it into the api header?

Tags: java, android, cookies, session-cookies, okhttp

There is cookie header in my api request, every time I have to copy this cookie from postman and paste in my code to make it work. how can I generate cookie in my app and give that value in cookie header?

this is my login code:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
  .build();
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
  .addFormDataPart("username","zee@earthonetechno.com")
  .addFormDataPart("password","E1234567")
  .build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("192.168.1.51/auth/login")
  .method("POST", body)
  .addHeader("User-Agent", "Koala Admin")
  .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
  .addHeader("Cookie", "session=3e3710cb-9b41-47ea-ab1b-a1e1801e188b")
  .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

I want to put the cookie here in `addHeader("Cookie", "session=3e3710cb-9b41-47ea-ab1b-a1e1801e188b")`

I am developing in android studio

Comment: Why do you want to generate cookie at app side ?

Comment: without this i am not able to login. what are my option?

Comment: Generate UUID randomly and treat it as Cookie

Comment: thanks, but not working for me

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this

just include these lines in login part to get cookie

```
Headers allHeaders = response.headers();
headerValue = allHeaders.get("Set-Cookie");
```

and use this `headerValue`  for subsequent api calls